# searching and replacing using turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

[The language consists of 'a's and 'b's. Capital 'B' depicts the end points of the string stored on the tape]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1H50.jpg

Search the string left-to-right for an a; as soon as one is found, replace
it by X, return to the left end, and search for b; replace it by X; return
to the left end and repeat these steps until one of the two searches is
unsuccessful.

Comment: Show what you have tried? This could get interesting.

Comment: I am not using any emulator. I just solve the problems on pen paper.

Comment: Also the first part of the problem searching 'a' and replacing it with 'X' is easy. I don't know how to move the head completely to the left then to search for 'b'

Comment: Ok, so please add to your question what you have already. It helps us. We need to see what standards you are using to layout rules and states and transitions A link to the documentation standards you are using will help.

Comment: I added the image but only link is showing up in the questions. not the image itself. 
Also that in the image I added I dont know at what state is the turing machine going to halt.